# Uploaded image taken from webcam is corrupted when uploaded to server

Tags: php, webcam

I am trying to upload image taken from webcam. I use canvas for showing that image and send base64_encoded json data by POST method to PHP and therefore in PHP decode the data and try to create an image by file_put_contents. But the uploaded image is corrupted every time. I used header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *") in PHP also. I also checked that the file_get_contents is enabled in the server. What may be the error? Please help.

My code is:

```
 JS:

// Trigger photo take

var imagedata;
document.getElementById('snap').addEventListener('click', function() {
   $('#canvas').show();
   context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
   $('#upload-button').removeAttr("disabled");
   var image = new Image();
   image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
   imagedata = image.src;
   $('#webimage').val(imagedata);
}); 

PHP:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$input_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
$base = $input_data['image'];
$destination_directory = "uploads/";
$file_name  =   time();
$file_name = $file_name.'.png';
$targetPath = $destination_directory . $file_name;
$input_data = base64_decode($base);
file_put_contents($targetPath, $input_data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever inspect the [data url of an image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)? It looks like this:

```
image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhyAAiALM...DfD0QAADs=
```

As you can see the actual base64 encoded representation of the binary content of the image starts after the comma. All you have to do is change:

```
$base = $input_data['image'];
```

to:

```
// php >= 5.4
$base = explode(',', $input_data['image'])[1];

// php < 5.4
list (, $base) = explode(',', $input_data['image']);
```

so the [base64_decode](http://php.net/base64_decode) function receives proper base64 string.

You are also missing proper validation inside your script:

- validate JSON input was decoded properly
- validate `image` key exists in the resulting array
- validate `base64_decode` did decode the string
- validate resulting image is a valid image (malicious users can embed PHP code for instance inside the image)

This way you can be 99% sure your server won't get compromised in the future.